# Dodge Durango Transmission Temperature via OBD2

Tags: transmission, obd-ii, durango

How can I read the transmission temperature on my 2012 Dodge Durango 5.7L Hemi via OBD2 (a wifi adapter - using Torque for Android and DashCommand for iOS)?

Comment: Note that for Apple devices, you need a Bluetooth ELM327 dongle, not the WiFi version.

Comment: Actually, in iOS you need a wifi adapter while Android supports both

Answer (score 1):

According to [this forum post](http://www.wranglerforum.com/f274/jk-transmission-temp-with-torque-app-565905.html), you need to do the following:

> Open up torque on your android device
> On the main screen hit the settings button (gear shaped button)
> -settings
> -manage extra PID's/Sensors
> -hit the menu button (mine is the three dots on the top right)
> -add predefined set
> -chrysler/dodge/jeep/mercedes
>
> Three PID's will come up. I just deleted the two I dont need. There is one for <2012 jk's and 2012+
>
> BOOM!
>
> Have to be in gear for it to pick up, otherwise it reverts to coolant temp.
> The PID is programmed to read Celsius and I edited it to F but thought it would throw off the calculation so I changed it back, deleted the gauge and re added it and it reads in F now like the rest.

A few entries down, there is also this post about what you need to insert if it isn't already there:

```
OBD2 mode and PID      2130
Long Name              Transmission Temp (Jeep 2012 and later)
Short Name             Trans.Fl.Tmp
Minimum value          0.0
Maximum Value          200
Scale Factor           x1
Unit type              °C
Equation               L-50
OBD Header             7E1
Diagnostic start       -blank-
diagnostic stop        -blank-
```

I'm sure one of the two methods would work for you.

Comment: Sweet!   Niiiice.   "Me too" ...  I'm only allowed one upvote; such a shame.

Comment: @SteveRacer did it work on your Durango?

Comment: They are registering at 0 on my Durango.